# kotlin : checking if a coroutine is finished before calling it again

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I have a listner method which is called very frequently. Within this method i launch a coroutine. I want to launch the coroutine only if the previous one is completed. Is there a better way to do it than I am doing with the boolean flag here

```
var ready = true;
        fun listenr(){

        if(ready){
    ready = false
            launch{
        //coroutine 
    ready = true
            }
    }
        }
```

Comment: `launch` returns a [`Job`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/) object, you can keep the reference and check if it `isActive`.

Comment: Launch returns job reference , and has method isActive to check if coroutine is still running. Checkout the reference for more details https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/is-active.html